# "Araqde" at bottom of main About page

Tags: bug, status-completed, about-page

I can't believe I just created an account solely to report this, but hey...

[image: <!--Lorum ipsum dolar wotsit -->]

Answer (score 2):

Oops! We'll get that fixed up on the next build, thanks for reporting!

Comment: Just noticed, there's also a weird triangle hovering over the 'out' of "Check out stackexchange"...

Comment: @Benjol - I built out a little while ago...not reproing this, are you still seeing it?  If so, which browser?

Comment: Ffx 15.0.1, I suppose it could be an extension. (Edit), nope, still there in safe mode.

Comment: @Benjol - turns out this looked just dandy in chrome...the bubble tails will be in their proper positions in other browsers after the next build.